# How to prevent alternate row selection in datagrid?

Tags: datagrid

Stop users from selecting alternate rows in datagrid in wpf.

User show select continuous rows not alternate rows of datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Im not completely sure what your question is exactly, but I think [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126345/wpf-datagrid-multiselect?rq=1) and the answers provide some background for MultiSelect in DataGrids. If you want to assert the selection, this might be done in the handler for the OnSelectionChanged event I suggest.

Comment: I means to say that end user shouldn't be able to select alternate rows in wpf datagrid.

Comment: You said that already, but it still doesn't make sense /I don't understand what you mean. Maybe try to tell me what _should_ the user do? Only select _one_ row? Or may he select multiple rows?